# ADXL345 with ESP32 I2C garbage value issue

Tags: arduino, accelerometer, i2c, esp32

I have connected my ESP32 with ADXL345 using I2C interface according to the tutorial followed from [Tutorial](http://www.esp32learning.com/code/esp32-and-adxl345-sensor-example.php)

However, when I run the code with the sensor flat on the table, shouldn't I be getting an output close to `X = 0.04, Y = 0.04, Z = 9.81 m/s^2.`
However, this is the output I am getting:

```
22:26:29.569 -> Xa= 254.00   Ya= 254.00   Za= 2.00
22:26:29.604 -> Xa= 254.00   Ya= 254.00   Za= 2.00
22:26:29.639 -> Xa= 254.00   Ya= 254.00   Za= 2.00
22:26:29.672 -> Xa= 254.00   Ya= 254.00   Za= 2.00
22:26:29.705 -> Xa= 254.00   Ya= 254.00   Za= 2.00
22:26:29.739 -> Xa= 254.00   Ya= 254.00   Za= 2.00
22:26:29.772 -> Xa= 254.00   Ya= 254.00   Za= 2.00
22:26:29.806 -> Xa= 254.00   Ya= 254.00   Za= 2.00
22:26:29.873 -> Xa= 254.00   Ya= 254.00   Za= 2.00
22:26:29.908 -> Xa= 254.00   Ya= 254.00   Za= 2.00
22:26:29.942 -> Xa= 254.00   Ya= 254.00   Za= 2.00
22:26:29.975 -> Xa= 254.00   Ya= 254.00   Za= 2.00
```

Moreover, the X and Y output do not change when I move the sensor.

Here is the code I am using :

```
#include <Wire.h>  // Wire library - used for I2C communication

int ADXL345 = 0x53; // The ADXL345 sensor I2C address

float X_out, Y_out, Z_out;  // Outputs

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Initiate serial communication for printing the 
                         results on the Serial monitor
  Wire.begin(); // Initiate the Wire library
  // Set ADXL345 in measuring mode
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345); // Start communicating with the device 
  Wire.write(0x2D); // Access/ talk to POWER_CTL Register - 0x2D
  // Enable measurement
  Wire.write(8); // (8dec -> 0000 1000 binary) Bit D3 High for measuring enable 
  Wire.endTransmission();
  delay(10);
}

void loop() {
  // === Read acceleromter data === //
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345);
  Wire.write(0x32); // Start with register 0x32 (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(ADXL345, 6, true); // Read 6 registers total, each axis value is stored in 2 registers
  X_out = ( Wire.read()| Wire.read() << 8); // X-axis value
  X_out = X_out/256; //For a range of +-2g, we need to divide the raw values by 256, according to the datasheet
  Y_out = ( Wire.read()| Wire.read() << 8); // Y-axis value
  Y_out = Y_out/256;
  Z_out = ( Wire.read()| Wire.read() << 8); // Z-axis value
  Z_out = Z_out/256;

  Serial.print("Xa= ");
  Serial.print(X_out);
  Serial.print("   Ya= ");
  Serial.print(Y_out);
  Serial.print("   Za= ");
  Serial.println(Z_out);
}
```

**UPDATES:**
Here is an Update to the output after making the suggested changes:

```
22:14:43.271 -> Xa= -2   Ya= -2   Za= 1
22:14:43.271 -> Xa= -2   Ya= -2   Za= 1
22:14:43.304 -> Xa= -2   Ya= -2   Za= 1
22:14:43.337 -> Xa= -2   Ya= -2   Za= 1
22:14:43.370 -> Xa= -2   Ya= -2   Za= 1
22:14:43.403 -> Xa= -2   Ya= -2   Za= 1
22:14:43.403 -> Xa= -2   Ya= -2   Za= 1
22:14:43.437 -> Xa= -2   Ya= -2   Za= 1
22:14:43.471 -> Xa= -2   Ya= -2   Za= 1
```

Here is the updated code:

```
#include <Wire.h>  // Wire library - used for I2C communication

int ADXL345 = 0x53; // The ADXL345 sensor I2C address

int16_t X_out, Y_out, Z_out;  // Outputs

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Initiate serial communication for printing the 
                       //  results on the Serial monitor
  Wire.begin(); // Initiate the Wire library
  // Set ADXL345 in measuring mode
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345); // Start communicating with the device 
  Wire.write(0x2D); // Access/ talk to POWER_CTL Register - 0x2D
  // Enable measurement
  Wire.write(8); // (8dec -> 0000 1000 binary) Bit D3 High for measuring enable 
  Wire.endTransmission();
  delay(10);
}

void loop() {
  // === Read acceleromter data === //
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345);
  Wire.write(0x32); // Start with register 0x32 (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom((uint16_t)ADXL345,(uint8_t) 6, true); // Read 6 registers total, each axis value is stored in 2 registers
  X_out = ( Wire.read()| Wire.read() << 8); // X-axis value
  X_out = X_out/256; //For a range of +-2g, we need to divide the raw values by 256, according to the datasheet
  Y_out = ( Wire.read()| Wire.read() << 8); // Y-axis value
  Y_out = Y_out/256;
  Z_out = ( Wire.read()| Wire.read() << 8); // Z-axis value
  Z_out = Z_out/256;

  Serial.print("Xa= ");
  Serial.print(X_out);
  Serial.print("   Ya= ");
  Serial.print(Y_out);
  Serial.print("   Za= ");
  Serial.println(Z_out);
}
```

The values of the Z axis does not seem to be changing when I change the orientation of the ADXL345 sensor. How could we solve this prolem?

Comment: Hi Aryaman, we need to see your code. Please post it as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The code in use was directly copied from the tutorial website. It is the most basic sensortest code available from AdaFruit library. However if you still require the code I would be happy to provide.

Comment: The usual requirement is to post your code on this site directly, as external resources can disappear; or you might have changed the original sample.

Comment: I have added the code in use.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your code and output don't match. Secondly, in your code you're reading a  2-byte signed integer value from a register and assigning it to a variable of type float. This will result in garbage. Use the correct type of variable (int16_t in this case). The [data sheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL345.pdf) for the accelerometer specifies the data format (section "*Register 0x32 to Register 0x37—DATAX0, DATAX1, DATAY0, DATAY1, DATAZ0, DATAZ1 (Read Only)*")

Comment: Yes noted, I have made the changes in the output. I have made the changes in variable type you suggested. And have put an update to the output I am receiving. However, there seems to be no considerable change in values of the Z axis. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: OK. How do you move the sensor when looking for changes? E.g. flipping it over would be an excellent test, as X and Y axis should remain as they are and Z should become negative, right?

Comment: Yes we flip it over to the negative Z direction. Even then the values don't seem to change. Shouldn't the values of X and Y be 0 and Z change between +1 and -1 ?

Comment: We are really stuck at this problem, and would really appreciate some help @Tarmo.

Comment: Unfortunately there's not much I can help with. Go through the data sheet and your code carefully, make sure every assumption you've made holds (e.g. you've chosen the alternate I2C address `0x53` - are you sure about that).

Comment: The only other thing I can point out is that you're chopping off all digits behind the decimal point with this line `X_out = X_out/256;` - you probably want to perform the division as a float or double operation instead of int (e.g.  `float X_f = (float)X_out/256.0F;`), and assign the result to a float or double.